# Replacing regular expression with keycode data

Tags: asp.net, regex, keyboard, validation, keycode

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsAlphaNumeric(ByVal entry As String) As Boolean
Get
    Return New Regex("(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zα-ωA-ZΑ-Ω]*$)^([a-zα-ωA-ZΑ-Ω0-9]{6,15})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(entry)
End Get

End Property
```

This one is pretty good for Greek and English language.

What about all the other languages in the universe?

Should i replace the above code with another function, validating keycode data and text length or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use unicode character definitions instead, such as `\p{L}` for letters and `\p{N}` for numbers.

You can find [documentation on which categories that are recognized at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories).

However, I am not sure whether it supports the Klingon alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

This one is brilliant also! Found at [a1vbcode.com](http://www.a1vbcode.com/snippet-104.asp)

```
Public Function IntlIsAlphaCharacter(sChar As String) As Boolean
    IntlIsAlphaCharacter = (Not (UCase(sChar) = LCase(sChar))) Or (sChar = " ")
End Function
```

The native language of klingons is regex's?